# Java how to good practice : Map in Utility Class

Tags: java, dictionary, utility-method

Can I use a utility class like this?

```java
public final class ProfessorDirectory {
    private static Map<String, Professor> directory = new HashMap<>();

    private ProfessorDirectory() {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Utility Class");
    }

    static void addProfessorsFromDescription(String description) {
        String regex = "(?<=\\n).*   .*(?=\\n)";
        Matcher m = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(description);
        while (m.find()) {
            String professorName = Professor.formater(m.group(0));
            directory.put(professorName, new Professor(professorName));
        }
    }

    public static Professor get(String firstName, String lastName) {
        return directory.get(Professor.formater(firstName, lastName));
    }

}
```

I used this to create a library in which you can retrieve a teacher's planning.

**Exemple of utilisation:**

```java
Planning professorPlanning = schedules.getPlanningOf(ProfessorDirectory.get("Jack", "Sticky"));
```

The `ProfessorDirectory` is initialized internally, and should never be initialized by the user.

Comment: What will happen if two,three, or four addProfessorsFromDescription are called at the same time for the same professor? And if you add a delete method? - hint: if a map is shared, synchronize it.

Comment: @aran For the moment it's never called several times because is utilized in a Singleton class.
But if that happens I think I would add a Synchronized in the add method.

Do you think it's a good solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few disadvantages to this approach, that is, the approach of having static data and methods.

1. You can never have more than one `ProfessorDirectory`, even if you find it would be useful to have several.
2. It is difficult to test clients of `ProfessorDirectory`, because they must use the real code instead of being able to mock an interface.
3. You rule out using some useful patterns. For instance, you can't write a caching proxy that implements a `ProfessorDirectory` interface and wraps an arbitrary implementation of that interface.

Overall this is a bad approach.

Comment: I voluntarily create this class to have just one `ProfessorDirectory` which contains all the teachers in the school. I tested this class here: https://github.com/DevLab-umontp/Librairie-Java-EDT/blob/main/src/test/java/fr/umontp/edt/RepertoireProfesseurTest.java
. Why create a caching proxy with a class that only uses a Map?

Comment: Your approach may be absolutely fine for your application, but I don't think it "follows good code practice within Java".